# Как сделать так, чтобы приложение созданное в Eclipse открывалось посередине экрана и не увеличивалось?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, gui

Возможно нужно код прописать. Я просто недавно начал и хотел бы узнать как можно сделать так. Буду благодарен любой помощи. Так-как я новичок могу не понять объяснения для про в этом деле.

Comment: Приложение, я так понимаю, не консольное? Swing? JavaFX?

Comment: java приложение. которое открывается после компилирования.

Comment: в общем не консольное

Comment: Нужна еще информация о том, с помощью чего Вы строите GUI.

Comment: Я просто работаю в Эклипс марс. Там просто сделал приложение. И когда я сделаю отдельное Джава приложение, мне нужно чтобы окно приложения оставалось посередине и не растягивалось.

Comment: При создании проекта Вы выбирали GUI.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
```

Устанавливаем текущее разрешение экрана

```
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    System.out.println(d.height + " " + d.width);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame(" test " );
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
```

Устанавливаем местонахождение окна

```
    frame.setLocation(((d.width /2)-frame.getWidth()/2) , ((d.height/2)-frame.getHeight()/2));
```

Убираем возможность изменения размера окна

```
   frame.setResizable(false);
```

Отображаем фрайм

```
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручили!